# iphone is not displaying My vue form on mobile data

Tags: ios, vue.js

My vue.js web App is working fine on browsers, Android (WIFI & Mobile Data),  but on iPhone, it works only if the iPhone is connected to WIFI, if iPhone is connected to the internet using mobile data, the page is not displayed!!.
Did anyone face something like this!!. I think that ios are setting a cap for traffic in the case of mobile data.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try it on Chrome or another browser in IOS?

Comment: Which app do you use to display the view ? How is cellular data set for it ?

Comment: I used Chrome and firefox, both gave the same results. and both work fine when the mobile is connected to WIFi

Comment: It is a Vue.js web Application